# How can I print_r an array from controller while an ajax process?

Tags: ajax, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to debug my AJAX call to database.

But there is no way to see the data i am using. I have tried to do it inserting some Javascript:

I also tried to use `print_r`, but nothing happens.

Is there any way to see my variables? A developer tool for example, or any command i could use.

Thanks for your help.

```
function console_log( $data ){
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'console.log('. json_encode( $data ) .')';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

This is my controller code:

```
public function searchEvents(){
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        if($request->getMethod()=='POST') {
            $value = $request->request->get('searchBox');
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $searchFor = $request->request->get('value');
            $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            //$eventos = $em->getRepository('App:Evento')->findBy(array('title'=>'Invi Chuwi'));
            $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT e FROM App:Evento e WHERE e.title LIKE :value');
            $query->setParameter('value', '%'.$searchFor.'%');
            $eventos = $query->getResult();
            /*$qb->select('u')
                ->from('App:Evento','u')
                ->where(('u.title = '.$searchFor));
            $query = $qb->getQuery();
            $eventos = $query->getResult();*/
            $response = [];
            foreach($eventos as $evento){
                array_unshift($response,[
                    $evento->getTitle(),
                    $evento->getFecha()
                ]);
                print_r($response);
            }
            $respuesta = new JsonResponse();
            $respuesta->setData(
                array('response'=>'success',
                    'eventos'=>$response)
            );
        }
        return $respuesta;
}
```

And my js code:

```
function searchForEvents(value){
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        data: value=2,
        url:"{{ path('searchEvents') }}",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            //var results = JSON.parse(data.events);
            alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
            //putEvents(results);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: As you can see, I am referencing a variable in the ajax process. But that variable doesn't seems to pass to the controller.
When i have an error, it looks like the variable is `'value_of_the_variable_from_ajax_call' = 'null'`.
Why could this being happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you send your AJAX request is invalid. Change it to:

```
function searchForEvents(value){
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        data: {value: 2},
        url:"{{ path('searchEvents') }}",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            //var results = JSON.parse(data.events);
            alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
            //putEvents(results);
        }
    })
}
```

This will still not pass `searchbox`, but hopefully this is enough to figure that out as well. If not, then please add more details.

As about debugging the data, you can always use the good old `echo var_dump` and see what it puts into your request response in the network tab of dev tools or you can do it the Symfony way, [logging](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html) it into a file.

Comment: Thanks! I just missed the ´{value}´.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use Symfony 4+ If this case you need to install Symfony Profiler and Var Dumper packages (https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html - https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html). When install that two bundle you need change `print_r` functions to `dump` function. After you do that profiler package record all your request. You can access profiler data to "_profiler" route (example: http://localhost:8000/_profiler/ or something like that).

Please notice that the browser will show you the direct link to profiler inside the headers of the request, here is an example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you question correctly, but AJAX requests have to be debugged separately using symfony developer toolbar or by peeking request in browsers dev tools → Network tab. You can also check var/log/dev.log

Comment: It is basically a search tool which refreshes onkeyup.

I am trying to get the JSON data from my database. But I cant know if it is getting the value of the text input into my symfony controller. And i am pretty sure it is not working because of that

Comment: Thanks anyway, i will take a look on some dev tools.